# How to search in an Array for integer and strlen

Tags: php, html, arrays

I would like to search in an Array if there is a key that has a stringlength of exactly 5 characters and further on it must be of type integer.

I tried:

```
$key = array_search( strlen( is_int($array)=== true) === 5 , $array);
```

but this does not work. So I would like to know if it exists and which key it is.

Thanks alot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about:

```
$filtered = array_filter($array, function($v){
  return !!(is_int($v)&&strlen($v)==5);
});
```

[run code](http://ideone.com/gPR9nP)

Essentially [`array_filter`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) iterates over each element of the array passing each value `$v` to a callable function.  Depending on your desired conditions it returns a boolean (true or false) as to whether it is kept in the resultant `$filtered` array.

the `!!` is not strictly necessary as `(...)` will ensure boolean is cast correctly but the exclamation marks are just syntactic sugar - personal preference for readability.

Comment: That's cool, how does it work? Consider explaining things if they aren't obvious (the OP is a beginner, so it isn't obvious). Adding comments to the code is a great way.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha fair enough, will do

Answer (score 1):

That's not how array_search() works. It searches the value for a matching string, and returns a key. If you want to search a key, your best bet is to simply iterate over it.

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {
    if (strlen($key) === 5) { 
        echo $key . ": " . $value; 
        break; //Finish the loop once a match is found
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

array_search will not work like this try

```
foreach ($array as $key => $value) {

if ((strlen($value) == 5) && is_int($value)) 
 { 
    echo $key . ": " . $value;  
 }
}
```

You can use [array_walk](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php)

```
array_walk($array, function(&$value, $index){
if (strlen($value) == 5 && (is_int($index))) echo "$index:$value";
});
```

array walk iterates through each element and applies the user defined function

Answer (score 1):

here is sample example to compare value with integer and exact 5 character

```
$array = array(12345,'asatae');

$key_val = array();
foreach($array as $each_val){    
    if(is_int($each_val) && strlen($each_val) == 5){        
        $key_val[] = $each_val;
    }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($key_val);
```

you output will be like

```
Array
(
    [0] => 12345
)
```

Notice : in array must be integer value not quotes

like array(23, "23", 23.5, "23.5")

23 is integer with first key..